# No overload for method 'CustomerOrderInsert' takes 10 arguments Blazor Server

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to save data from a syncfusion editform
I really cant figure out what I'm doing wrong or why im getting that error.

```
  private async Task OrderLineSave()
{

    await CustomerOrderService.CustomerOrderInsert(addeditOrderLine.OrderProductID = ProductID,
        addeditOrderLine.OrderCustomerName,
        addeditOrderLine.OrderCustomerPhoneNumber,
        addeditOrderLine.OrderDeliveryAddress,
        addeditOrderLine.OrderInscription,
        addeditOrderLine.OrderInstruction,
        addeditOrderLine.OrderDeliveryDate,
         addeditOrderLine.OrderPickupTime,
          addeditOrderLine.OrderRecipient,
        addeditOrderLine.OrderFlavor);
}
```

below is my service class

```
 public async Task<bool> CustomerOrderInsert(CustomerOrder customerorder)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("OrderProductID", customerorder.OrderProductID, DbType.Int32);
            parameters.Add("OrderCustomerName", customerorder.OrderCustomerName, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("OrderCustomerPhoneNumber", customerorder.OrderCustomerPhoneNumber, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("OrderDeliveryAddress", customerorder.OrderDeliveryAddress, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("OrderInscription", customerorder.OrderInscription, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("OrderInstruction", customerorder.OrderInstruction, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("OrderDeliveryDate", customerorder.OrderDeliveryDate, DbType.DateTime);
            parameters.Add("OrderPickupTime", customerorder.OrderPickupTime, DbType.DateTime);
            parameters.Add("OrderRecipient", customerorder.OrderRecipient, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("OrderFlavor", customerorder.OrderFlavor, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("OrderIsArchived", customerorder.OrderIsArchived, DbType.Boolean);

            // Stored procedure method
            await conn.ExecuteAsync("spCustomerOrder_Insert", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What is `addeditOrderLine`?

Comment: The DB server is rejecting your call, as it has no variant of the DB function `CustomerOrderInsert` that takes 10 arguments. The exception seems very straightforward and clear. The Query seems to be inherently invalid.

Comment: The method expects 1 parameter, you're passing 10 parameters.  Did you mean to create an instance of `CustomerOrder` first and pass that to the method?

Comment: @spender that is the model name given to the syncfusion editform.

Comment: @Christopher so would that mean i need to check the DB server on that stored procedure ? I'm really new to these so i might not really be clear on what exactly to do.

Comment: @David , I'm not so clear on what you asking.. i'm a beginner. But my plan was to call the `CustomerOrderInsert` method and insert the data provided in the editform to CustomerOrder table in the DB

Comment: @BootDat Apparently I was wrong, and the error was a Compiler error. But it was the same one: "I have no idea what you want me to do - I can not _find_ a override of  'CustomerOrderInsert' that would accept that list of 10 Arguments!"  | Now that I look at it again, the answer was in the provided code. But even if not, very few compiler called functions would accept 10 seperate Arguments in a row. Anywhere past 3, most people write a class or struct like `CustomerOrder` whose sole purpose is to hold those 10+ Arguments as fields.

Comment: @christopher , sure. I understand. Really appreciate it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method expects *one* parameter:

```
public async Task<bool> CustomerOrderInsert(CustomerOrder customerorder)
                                         // ^--------- here ----------^
```

It's expecting a single instance of a `CustomerOrder` object.  But when you call the method you are supplying *ten* parameters:

```
CustomerOrderService.CustomerOrderInsert(addeditOrderLine.OrderProductID = ProductID,
    addeditOrderLine.OrderCustomerName,
    addeditOrderLine.OrderCustomerPhoneNumber,
    addeditOrderLine.OrderDeliveryAddress,
    addeditOrderLine.OrderInscription,
    addeditOrderLine.OrderInstruction,
    addeditOrderLine.OrderDeliveryDate,
    addeditOrderLine.OrderPickupTime,
    addeditOrderLine.OrderRecipient,
    addeditOrderLine.OrderFlavor)
```

By their names these appear to be individual values, but they're definitely not a single object.

Would `addeditOrderLine` happen to be an instance of `CustomerOrder`?  If so, just pass that to the method:

```
CustomerOrderService.CustomerOrderInsert(addeditOrderLine)
```

If not then you'll need to create an instance of `CustomerOrder`.  Initially that could be as simple as:

```
CustomerOrderService.CustomerOrderInsert(new CustomerOrder())
```

But of course this would be a new instance with only default values.  If you want to add your values to that instance then you'd have to do that however you normally would when creating that instance.  Maybe as constructor arguments, for example.  Or maybe you create an instance first, set all its values individually, and then call the method with that instance.

Ultimately that part is up to you, since we don't know what `addeditOrderLine` is or what a `CustomerOrder` is.  But the root of the error itself is pretty straightforward... The method expects a single `CustomerOrder` object and not a bunch of individual values.

Comment: Thanks @David  i passes `addeditOrderLine` to the method and it was fine.